# Codeigniter to json bug fixing

Tags: json, codeigniter

I make a simple code for `JSON` api like that:

```
<?php
class Json extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->helper('url_helper');
            $this->load->database();
    }
     public function index()
    {
        $user = $this->db->get('user');
        echo '{"user": [';

        foreach ($user->result() as $row)
        {
            echo "{";
                echo '"name" : "'. $row->user;
                echo '", "password" : "'. $row->password;
                echo '", "email" : "'. $row->email;
            echo '"},';
        }
        echo ']}';   
    }
}
```

Result is

```
{"user": [{"name" : "admin", "password" : "abcd", "email" : "deenjustin@gmail.com"},{"name" : "deenj", "password" : "dfgh", "email" : "deenj.effects@gmail.com"},]}
```

The issue is the the comma repeating. Please help to fix the bug.

Comment: Don't you need to get the result from your query like this: $user = $this->db->get('user')->result();? First, that code should really be in a model. Second, instead of getting the result as an object you could just get instead as an array which you could just pass to json_encode() and get rid  of the foreach altogether

Comment: Pacio can gate fore details about. json_encode()

Comment: json_encode(['name' => $row->user, 'email' => $row->email]). Also you should not be sending the users password. It should be hashed and stored within your DB, never to be taken out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a comma before the object except the first one:

```
public function __construct()
{
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url_helper');
        $this->load->database();
}
 public function index()
{
    $user = $this->db->get('user');
    $index = 0;
    echo '{"user": [';

    foreach ($user->result() as $row)
    {
        if (!($index++)) echo ",";
        echo "{";
            echo '"name" : "'. $row->user;
            echo '", "password" : "'. $row->password;
            echo '", "email" : "'. $row->email;
        echo '"}';
    }
    echo ']}';   
}
```

}

Comment: Donn't need in first last. Only for separation.

Comment: @DeenJustin have you actually tested this code? It should write something like {"user": [{"name" : "admin", "password" : "abcd", "email" : "deenjustin@gmail.com"},{"name" : "deenj", "password" : "dfgh", "email" : "deenj.effects@gmail.com"}]}. The code will put a comma before all elements except the first.

Comment: f (($index++)) echo ",";  Thanks to all .  Pacio can gate fore details about. json_encode()

Answer (score 2):

json_encode converts a standard php array to json. Like I said, your call to the db looks wrong to me, but it doesn't seem to give you an error, so I don't know what's going on there. But this is what it looks to me like how it should be:

```
 public function __construct()
    {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->helper('url_helper');
            $this->load->database();
    }
     public function index()
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('user');
        $user = $query->result_array();
        echo json_encode($user);
}
```

Aside from my question about how you get your data, if you can convert $user to a standard key=>value array the json_encode() function will do the rest.

Comment: $user = $query->result_array(); Ok I fix it. thank you so much.